# iOS8 Universal storyboard how to refactor split view controller using size classes on iPhone?

Tags: master-detail, ios8, xcode6, universal-storyboard

I've converted my storyboard that uses split view controller to size classes using xCode 6 beta 3. Upon running the application, I see that the detail panel shows up first and has a "back" button in navigation. That button brings me to the master view. However, I cannot navigate back to detail view controller from  master.

**Is there a way for me to keep using master/detail approach in a universal storyboard?**